# How to change button text and color in android?

Tags: android

I am making an app in which there is a `button` and when a user click on that button it will fetch the latitude and longitude of user and prompt to open that using google map and when I click on button it is changing the text and color of button but what I want is when it prompt to open that in maps and if user click outside that view then the button will change to its original text .I am having relative layout and in relative layout I have a method `setOnClickListener` so that when user click outside button it will change to original bt if the prompt is open then it is not working .`

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=" + mylatitude + "," + mylongitude + "&daddr=" + locationofuserlat + "," + locationofuserlong;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an application"));`
```

This is my code when it prompts and I click outside that then the button will not change.

Comment: Where is the codes, related with changing color and text of your button?

Comment: Have a onClickListener for view and change the text and colour of button when clicked on view

Comment: So you just want to change color of button when it is pressed?